# Hardhat throws 'ProviderError: HttpProviderError' when I run my deploy script

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

I'm trying to deploy my contract to the goerli testnet however hardhat keeps throwing this error:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xb5E8683Aa524069C5714Fc2D8c3e64F78f2862fb","data":"0x6103e86009556... (I shortened it down)","accessList":null}, error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: HttpProviderError\n    at HttpProvider.request (C:\\Programming\\Personal Projects\\NFT Minting Dapp\\smart-contract\\node_modules\\hardhat\\src\\internal\\core\\providers\\http.ts:78:19)\n    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (C:\\Programming\\Personal Projects\\NFT Minting Dapp\\smart-contract\\node_modules\\hardhat\\src\\internal\\core\\providers\\accounts.ts:187:34)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (C:\\Programming\\Personal Projects\\NFT Minting Dapp\\smart-contract\\node_modules\\@nomiclabs\\hardhat-ethers\\src\\internal\\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)","code":3,"_isProviderError":true,"data":"0xbfc6c337000000000000000000000000fd7bfa171b5b81b79c245456e986db2f32fbfadb"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Programming\Personal Projects\NFT Minting Dapp\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Programming\Personal Projects\NFT Minting Dapp\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at checkError (C:\Programming\Personal Projects\NFT Minting Dapp\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:78:20)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (C:\Programming\Personal Projects\NFT Minting Dapp\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:642:20)
    at step (C:\Programming\Personal Projects\NFT Minting Dapp\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (C:\Programming\Personal Projects\NFT Minting Dapp\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (C:\Programming\Personal Projects\NFT Minting Dapp\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'execution reverted',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0xb5E8683Aa524069C5714Fc2D8c3e64F78f2862fb',
    data: '0x6103e86009556... (I shortened it down)',
    accessList: null
  }
```

Here is my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

/// @title John's ERC721A Contract
/// @author John Pioc (www.johnpioc.com)
/// @notice This contract can be used to mint ERC721A standard NFTs with industry standard functionality - whitelisted addresses, reveals, NFT metadata, etc.

import "erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol";
import {DefaultOperatorFilterer} from "./DefaultOperatorFilterer.sol";

error CallerIsNotUser();
error InvalidWhitelistAllocation();
error MintingTooMany();
error InsufficientFunds();
error MintingOverCollectionSize();
error SaleIsClosed();
error MintingOverWhitelistAllocation();
error InvalidProof();
error URIQueryForNonexistentToken();

contract NFT is ERC721A, Ownable, DefaultOperatorFilterer {

    using Strings for uint256;

    enum SaleState {
        CLOSED,
        WHITELIST,
        PUBLIC
    }

    uint256 public collectionSize = 1000;
    uint256 public publicMintPrice = 0.1 ether;
    uint256 public publicMaxMintAmount = 3;
    uint256 public whitelistAllocation = 500;
    uint256 public whitelistMintPrice = 0.05 ether;
    uint256 public whitelistMaxMintAmount = 1;
    bytes32 public whitelistMerkleRoot;
    string public unrevealedUri = "https://exampleUnrevealedUri.com";
    string public baseUri = "https://exampleUri.com/";
    bool public isRevealed;
    SaleState public saleState;

    /// @notice Modifier to verify that caller doesn't come from a contract
    modifier callerIsUser() {
        if (tx.origin != msg.sender) revert CallerIsNotUser();
        _;
    }

    constructor() ERC721A ("NFT", "NFT") {
        isRevealed = false;
        saleState = SaleState.CLOSED;
    }

    /// @notice Function to mint NFTs during the public sale
    /// @param _mintAmount Number of NFTs to mint
    function publicMint(uint64 _mintAmount) public payable callerIsUser {
        if (_numberMinted(msg.sender) - _getAux(msg.sender) + _mintAmount > publicMaxMintAmount) revert MintingTooMany();
        if (totalSupply() + _mintAmount > collectionSize) revert MintingOverCollectionSize();
        if (saleState != SaleState.PUBLIC) revert SaleIsClosed();
        if (msg.value < _mintAmount * publicMintPrice) revert InsufficientFunds();

        _safeMint(msg.sender, _mintAmount);
    }

    /// @notice Function to mint NFTs during the whitelist sale
    /// @param _merkleProof Merkle Proof for caller's address
    /// @param _mintAmount Number of NFTs to mint
    function whitelistMint(bytes32[] calldata _merkleProof, uint64 _mintAmount) public payable callerIsUser {
        if (_getAux(msg.sender) + _mintAmount > whitelistMaxMintAmount) revert MintingTooMany();
        if (totalSupply() + _mintAmount > whitelistAllocation) revert MintingOverWhitelistAllocation();
        if (saleState != SaleState.WHITELIST) revert SaleIsClosed();
        if (msg.value < _mintAmount * whitelistMintPrice) revert InsufficientFunds();

        bytes32 leaf = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender));
        if(!(MerkleProof.verify(_merkleProof, whitelistMerkleRoot, leaf))) revert InvalidProof();

        _setAux(msg.sender, _getAux(msg.sender) + _mintAmount);
        _safeMint(msg.sender, _mintAmount);
    }

    /// @notice Sets a new collection size
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function
    /// @param _collectionSize New Collection Size
    function setCollectionSize(uint256 _collectionSize) public onlyOwner {
        collectionSize = _collectionSize;
    }

    /// @notice Sets a new public mint price
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function
    /// @param _publicMintPrice New public mint price
    function setPublicMintPrice(uint256 _publicMintPrice) public onlyOwner {
        publicMintPrice = _publicMintPrice;
    }

    /// @notice Sets a new public max mint amount
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function
    /// @param _publicMaxMintAmount New public max mint amount
    function setPublicMaxMintAmount(uint256 _publicMaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner {
        publicMaxMintAmount = _publicMaxMintAmount;
    }

    /// @notice Sets a new whitelist allocation
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function. New whitelist allocation cannot be greater than collection size
    /// @param _whitelistAllocation New whitelist allocation
    function setWhitelistAllocation(uint256 _whitelistAllocation) public onlyOwner {
        if (_whitelistAllocation > collectionSize) revert InvalidWhitelistAllocation();
        whitelistAllocation = _whitelistAllocation;
    }

    /// @notice Sets a new whitelist mint price
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function
    /// @param _whitelistMintPrice New whitelist mint price
    function setWhitelistMintPrice(uint256 _whitelistMintPrice) public onlyOwner {
        whitelistMintPrice = _whitelistMintPrice;
    }

    /// @notice Sets a new whitelist max mint amount
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function
    /// @param _whitelistMaxMintAmount New whitelist max mint amount
    function setWhitelistMaxMintAmount(uint256 _whitelistMaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner {
        whitelistMaxMintAmount = _whitelistMaxMintAmount;
    }

    /// @notice Sets a new whitelist merkle root
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function
    /// @param _whitelistMerkleRoot New whitelist merkle root
    function setWhitelistMerkleRoot(bytes32 _whitelistMerkleRoot) public onlyOwner {
        whitelistMerkleRoot = _whitelistMerkleRoot;
    }

    /// @notice Sets a new unrevealed URI
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function
    /// @param _unrevealedUri New unrevealed URI
    function setUnrevealedUri(string memory _unrevealedUri) public onlyOwner {
        unrevealedUri = _unrevealedUri;
    }

    /// @notice Sets a new base URI
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function
    /// @param _baseUri New base URI
    function setBaseUri(string memory _baseUri) public onlyOwner {
        baseUri = _baseUri;
    }

    /// @notice Toggles reveal from false to true, vice versa
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function. Starts at false
    function toggleRevealed() public onlyOwner {
        isRevealed = !isRevealed;
    }

    /// @notice Sets a new sale state
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function. 0 = CLOSED, 1 = WHITELIST, 2 = PUBLIC
    /// @param _saleState new sale state
    function setSaleState(uint256 _saleState) public onlyOwner {
        saleState = SaleState(_saleState);
    }

    /// @notice Generates and returns the token URI for a given token ID
    /// @param _tokenId An NFT's token ID
    function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        if (!_exists(_tokenId)) revert URIQueryForNonexistentToken();
        if (!isRevealed) return unrevealedUri;

        return string(abi.encodePacked(baseUri, _tokenId.toString(), ".json"));
    }

    /// @notice Withdraws all ETH from contract to owner's address
    /// @dev Only owner can call this function
    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
        (bool os,) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(os);
    }

    /// @notice All functions below are mandatory add-ons as per the Default Operator Filterer protocol

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public payable override onlyAllowedOperator(from) {
        super.transferFrom(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public payable override onlyAllowedOperator(from) {
        super.safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory data)
        public
        payable
        override
        onlyAllowedOperator(from)
    {
        super.safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, data);
    }
}
```

Here is my config file:

```
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle";
import "dotenv/config";
import "@typechain/hardhat";

const GOERLI_RPC_URL = process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.17",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY!],
      chainId: 5,
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
    }
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      goerli: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY!
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

and here is my deploy script:

```
// imports
import { ethers, run, network } from 'hardhat';

// async main
async function main() {
  const contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFT");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  console.log(`Contract deployed to ${contract.address}`);

  if (network.config.chainId === 5 && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
    console.log("Waiting for block confirmations...")
    await contract.deployTransaction.wait(6)
    await verify(contract.address, [])
  }
}

// async function verify(contractAddress, args) {
const verify = async (contractAddress: string, args: any[]) => {
  console.log("Verifying contract...")
  try {
    await run("verify:verify", {
      address: contractAddress,
      constructorArguments: args,
    })
  } catch (e: any) {
    if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
      console.log("Already Verified!")
    } else {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}

// main
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

I ran the command:

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.ts --network goerli
```

And by running that command, it throws the error. I double checked that the it's grabbing the environment variables and everything. I actually forked all this code from one of my repos where the deploy script worked back then, however now it's not

Answer (score 0):

I've had some similar issues when using hardhat to deploy for both goerli and mainnet. What seemed to solve it for me is manually adding in a gas limit and gas price, here is what your goerli config object should look like, just be aware you'll want to adjust the limit and price to account for current gas prices.

```
goerli: {
      url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY!],
      chainId: 5,
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
      gas: 5000000, //units of gas you are willing to pay, aka gas limit
      gasPrice:  50000000000, //gas is typically in units of gwei, but you must enter it as wei here
    }
```

Reading the hardhat config docs is also worth a look [here](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config)

Check the eth gas tracker to see up to date [gas price estimates](https://etherscan.io/gastracker)

Answer (score 0):

In hardhat config file
provide this property with your api key.

```
 etherscan: {
    apiKey: "",
  },
```

You can achieve API key by signing in etherscan in case of mainnet or basescan in case of basenet.